# knockout.js and timing of observable update

Tags: knockout.js, blur, observable

I'm using knockout to bind some text fields to observables.  For now I'm using the default behavior where the vm is updated on the blur of the text box.  I know I can change the behavior to update the vm on other events like keydown or onchange but I'd like to prevent that if possible.

For a workaround, in my "Save" functionality, the first thing I do is set focus to the "Save" button/link that the user clicked on.  I don't know why that doesn't happen by default by the browser, but no big deal.  Setting focus explicitly causes the onblur of the edit box if that was the last field the user was on.  This updates the vm and things look good.  If the user enters data and I DON'T do the set focus, that observable in the vm is not updated.

My testing has been done on a relatively fast device.  I'm wondering if there is a small time interval between the time I set focus to the button/link and the time the vm observable is updated from the blur event of the edit box.  Right after I set focus I continue immediately with saving the data.  So far no issues, the data has been there every time.  But can I be guaranteed of that on slower devices.

Along the same lines, is there a method I can call that would cause all the obs variables to be updated from their bound UI elements, and that would return a promise when all variables are updated?  Then I could continue on with my Save.

Just looking for options that don't involve updating the variables on every key stroke or change event, but also making sure I get the last change.

thanks

EDIT: The problem is that if a user edits a bound field, then clicks the Save button, the changes for that edit box are not updated in the vm because a blur event has not occurred.  I am forcing a blur by setting focus myself.  But I am concerned that there could be a timing issue between the time I set focus (which causes the blur) and the time the vm is updated.

view code:

```
<input data-bind="value: accountName" placeholder="Enter Account Name"/>
```

vm :

```
var accountName= ko.observable('');
```

Setting focus in my Save Function

```
$('#btnSave').focus();
(continue save processing here.  Need to make sure accountName has been updated)
```

Comment: You mention a "workaround" before mentioning the actual problem. You should really put your concerns into some code, give us a repro of what you're talking about. I get the general idea, but see no real issue tbh.

Comment: Could you please provide a jsfiddle or similar which shows your problem? I have a jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/4QJTS/ based on the code samples you have provided and it does not need any manual focus handling to work as expected.

Comment: your fiddle works fine.  I even modified it to use a <a> instead of a <button> and it worked.  I'm using a framework called Durandal with KO, and also bootstrap.  In my version when I debug into the save function, self.accountName() does not have the same value as the edit box.  The only way to get self.accountName() to have the same value is to tab out of the field before clicking save, or explicitly setting focus to another control as the first line in the Save function. I'm doing the latter but still concerned about timing.  Seems to be an issue with other components, not KO.  thanks

Comment: If you can make a jsfiddle which shows your problem (as minimal as possible, only enough to demonstrate your issue) it would help a lot in trying to assist you.

Comment: i cant duplicate it with a simple example, it only happens when I have all my libraries in play.  Something is stepping on the sync process between the view and vm.  For now, I've forced a "blur" by setting focus to an <a> tag.  That causes the update so its good.  A bad side affect is that on an IPAD it causes the virtual keyboard to go away.  It's frustrating using frameworks of existing libraries.  Difficult to tell what software is causing the issue.